# objective-c syntax highlighting for vim

Tags: macos, vim, xcode, syntax-highlighting, color-theme

I would like to have an excellent syntax highliter for obj-c that matches or beats the one in my xcode..

I've installed [base16](https://github.com/chriskempson/base16-vim) through [yadr](https://github.com/skwp/dotfiles), and i've also installed [cocoa.vim](https://github.com/msanders/cocoa.vim) to have better syntax highlighting.. but installing the latter didn't change much and this is what I have:

[image]

contrast that with the [zenburn for xcode](https://github.com/an0/Zenburn-for-Xcode) color highlighting on the same file:

[image]

apart from the difference in colors (which is a personal preference thing and is **not** what i'm asking about).. i noticed that the zenburn for xcode recognized a lot more stuff than the vim one.. how can i address that in vim? I really wanna do all my development on vim going forward.

p.s. i'm not sure if cocoa.vim above does the same job as what [this](https://github.com/othree/javascript-libraries-syntax.vim) repo does for javascript for example.. you can get a visual for that difference [here](https://github.com/skwp/dotfiles/issues/434)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will probably need to do rather large edits in these two files:

```
https://github.com/msanders/cocoa.vim/blob/master/after/syntax/objc_enhanced.vim
https://github.com/msanders/cocoa.vim/blob/master/after/syntax/cocoa_keywords.vim
```

to match XCode's syntax highlighting. That's a non-trivial task that you can't really expect anybody here to do for you. The facts that a) those files are 4 years old and b) their author has completely ceased to support his Vim stuff don't make it any simpler.

I'm not aware of a single comprehensive online tutorial on writing your own syntax script so you won't be able to escape reading `:help syntax` from top to bottom and back and taking a look at other syntax scripts in `$VIMRUNTIME/syntax/`.

FWIW, the highlight groups defined by cocoa.vim are all linked to these seven standard highlight groups (I've added their hex value taken from your colorscheme):

```
Keyword    #b48ead
Special    #96b5b4
Type       #d08770
Constant   #d08770
Error      no value
String     #a3be8c
Identifier #bf616a
```

You'll notice that, in base16, `Type` and `Constant` have the same colors which may not be a good thing. From your XCode screenshot, it doesn't seem that it uses more colors than base16 so adding a couple of syntax groups might be enough.

Answer (score 4):

> I've installed base16 through yadr, and i've also installed cocoa.vim to have better syntax highlighting.. but installing the latter didn't change much and this is what I have:

That is because cocoa.vim has not been maintained for years and the syntax file doesn't fit with the latest Vim.

I just fixed it in my fork:
https://github.com/kentaroi/cocoa.vim

I don't have any intention to promote my fork.  But, in view of the current official cocoa.vim ( https://github.com/msanders/cocoa.vim )'s situation, I put a link of my fork for your convenience.

---

#### Edit:

Since I won't maintain the above repository anymore, I recommend the following vim syntax plugin:
https://github.com/SolaWing/vim-objc-syntax

Comment: Please be careful promoting your own content. This isn't spam, but please disclose your affiliation. (+1 for useful answer, though.)

Comment: Thank you for advising me! I edited my answer. Is it OK now?